# Javascript: why Object.keys(someobject), rather than someobject.keys?

Tags: javascript, arrays, oop, language-design, javascript-objects

I frequently get an array of an objects keys using:

```
Object.keys(someobject)
```

I'm comfortable doing this. I understand that Object is the Object constructor function, and keys() is a method of it, and that keys() will return a list of keys on whatever object is given as the first parameter. My **question is not how to get the keys of an object** - please do not reply with  non-answers explaining this.

My question is, **why isn't there a more predictable keys() or getKeys() method, or keys instance variable available on Object.prototype**, so I can have:

```
someobject.keys()
```

or as an instance variable:

```
someobject.keys
```

And return the array of keys?

Again, my intention is to understand the design of Javascript, and what purpose the somewhat unintuitive mechanism of fetching keys serves. I don't need help getting keys.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I guess an answer to your question is "Because the committee decided so", but I can already hear you ask "why?" before the end of this sentence.

I read about this recently but I can't find the source right now. What it boiled down to was that in many cases you had to use `Object.prototype.keys.call(myobject)` anyway, because the likelihood of `myobject.keys` already being used in the object for something else.

I think you will find this [archived mail thread](http://www.mail-archive.com/es-discuss@mozilla.org/msg03982.html) interesting, where for example *Brendan Eich* discuss some aspects of the new methods in ECMAScript 5.

**Update:**
While digging in the [mail-archive](https://mail.mozilla.org/pipermail/es-discuss/) I found [this](https://mail.mozilla.org/pipermail/es-discuss/2008-August/006828.html):

> **Topic**: Should Object.keys be repositioned as Object.prototype.keys
>
> **Discussion**: Allen argued that this isn't really a meta layer operation
>   as it is intended for use in application layer code as an alternative
>   to for..in for getting a list of enumerable property names. As a
>   application layer method it belongs on Object.prototype rather than on
>   the Object constructor.  There was general agreement in principle, but
>   it was pragmatically argued by Doug and Mark that it is too likely
>   that a user defined object would define its own property named "keys"
>   which would shadow Object.prototype.keys making it inaccessible for
>   use on such objects.
>
> **Action: Leave it as Object.keys.**

Answer (score 18):

I suppose they don't want too many properties on `Object.prototype` since your own properties could shadow them.

The more they include, the greater the chance for conflict.

---

It would be very clumsy to get the keys for this object if `keys` was on the `prototype`...

```
var myObj: {
   keys: ["j498fhfhdl89", "1084jnmzbhgi84", "jf03jbbop021gd"]
};

var keys = Object.prototype.keys.call(myObj);
```

---

***An example of how introducing potentially shadowed properties can break code.***

There seems to be some confusion as to why it's a big deal to add new properties to `Object.prototype`.

It's not at all difficult to conceive of a bit of code in existence that looks like this...

```
if (someObject.keys) {
    someObject.keys.push("new value")
else
    someObject.keys = ["initial value"]
```

Clearly this code would break if you add a `keys` function to `Object.prototype`. The fact that `someObject.keys` would now be a shadowing property breaks the code that is written to assume that it is *not* a shadowing property.

---

***Hindsight is 20/20***

If you're wondering why `keys` wasn't part of the original language, so that people would at least be accustomed to coding around it... well I guess they didn't find it necessary, or simply didn't think of it.

There are many possible methods and syntax features that aren't included in the language. That's why we have revisions to the specification, in order to add new features. For example, `Array.prototype.forEach` is a late addition. But they could add it to `Array.prototype`, because it doesn't break proper uses of `Array`.

It's not a realistic expectation that a language should include every possible feature in its `1.0` release.

Since `Object.keys` does nothing more than return an Array of an Object's enumerable own properties, it's a non-essential addition, that could be achieved with existing language features. It should be no surprise that it wasn't present earlier.

---

***Conclusion***

Adding `keys` to `Object.prototype` most certainly *would* break legacy code.

In a tremendously popular language like JavaScript, backward compatibility is most certainly going to be an important consideration. Adding new properties to `Object.prototype` at this point could prove to be disastrous.

Comment: +1. Yes, I imagine there was/is a lot of JS code out there similar to the object in your example. It would be pretty annoying if a new feature in the language forced changes in legacy code.

Comment: Would someone like to explain the down-vote? Please explain which part of my answer is incorrect.

Comment: @amnotiam There's no reason the ES3 or ES5 specs couldn't have made 'keys' or 'getkeys' reserved words. This same logic could apply to any other reserved word.

Comment: @nailer: There's a huge reason they couldn't do that. They can't easily create new reserved words since it'll break old code that uses those words. And "likelihood" is very hard to determine. I'd say that `getKeys` has a relatively high likelihood, or for that matter any other name that begins with `get` since it's not at all unusual to use accessor functions to reach local variables that are otherwise unreachable.

Comment: @amnotiam Please read my response again - I have not mentioned creating new reserved words. We are discussing the original design of the language.

Comment: @nailer: You said *"There's no reason the ES3 or ES5 specs couldn't have made 'keys' or 'getkeys' reserved words"*. To do that would be to add new reserved words to the specification.

Comment: @amnotiam I would have included the original specification for the language, but I'm not sure there *was* one. If it helps, you can change the sentence to 'reserved words in the ES3 spec or ES5 spec or Brenden Eich's notepad'. The original question remains: why not include a predictable keys variable or getKeys method the first time around?

Comment: @nailer: If you're interested, here's an example of the cost of reserving new words: ES3 had `goto` as a reserved word, but ES5 "unreserved" it. Now it was found to have potential use in ES6. In this paragraph entitled [Lost Opportunity](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:proper_tail_calls#lost_opportunity), David Herman of Mozilla and TC39 laments the "unreserve"  of `goto` as it would be too costly to reserve it again, even after such a short time.

Comment: @amnotiam I'm interested, but not in the scope of this discussion as mentioned. Why was 'static' important enough to reserve but something as simple as fetching keys considered less important? 'People might want to to use it for their own means', while adding to the discussion, isn't a sufficient explanation.

Comment: @nailer: I'm just responding to your comments. `static` is already there. Why `keys` or `getKeys` weren't reserved earlier isn't relevant. They weren't. As such, they aren't, and reserving them now would break code. Remember, `Object.keys` is an ES5 addition. It didn't exist before then.

Comment: ...and it's not *"People might want to to use it for their own means..."*, but rather *"People are likely already using it for their own means..."* Those uses would turn into broken code. There's a strong desire to maintain backward compatibility. One proposal was to fix `typeof null`, so that it didn't return `"object"`, but that proposal has been removed, since it breaks too much legacy code. http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:typeof_null

Comment: @amnotiam "Why keys or getKeys weren't reserved earlier isn't relevant." Pardon? The question is "why isn't there a more predictable keys() or getKeys() method". Understanding why these things weren't reserved earlier is **essential** to answering that.

Comment: @nailer: As I've stated, `Object.keys` wasn't part of the language specification until ECMAScript 5. At that point, it was considered too late to reserve them, because, as I stated above *"they can't easily create new reserved words since it'll break old code that uses those words."*

Comment: Note that the methods on `Object` aren't actually reserved words. It is not a syntax error to say `Object.keys = function() {alert("I broke it")}`. And you can do the same for methods on the prototype: `x = { hasOwnProperty : function(){return false;});` and `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty = function () { alert("Hi"); }` both work.

Comment: @nnnnnn: Makes a valid point. The "reserved word" really has little to do with anything, unless the question is changed to *"why aren't all methods in JavaScript reserved?"*. There are other essential properties that aren't reserved as well, like `undefined`.

Comment: @amnotiam Yes, I read your comment earlier. However, as I've mentioned, restating that something is the way it is, or that "static was reserved, keys wasn't" completely ignores the motivation behind these situations. I suggest we do not continue this discussion, as it it not contributing to StackOverflow or undercovering the motivations behind the present mechanism of enumerating keys of an object - see the original question.

Comment: @nnnnnn Interesting. That inbuilt methods are not reserved makes even more of a case for something common like enumerating keys to be built into the language, either at inception or at a later stage.

Comment: @nailer: `Object.keys` is not a mechanism of enumeration. JavaScript *has* enumeration syntax, called `for-in`. *"... completely ignores the motivation behind these situations"* The motivation for what? To not reserve words they haven't yet thought of as relevant to the language? Reserved words limit the vocabulary a developer has available to express code. Is that what you're asking? This has gone far beyond your original question.

Comment: @amnotiam 1. Object.keys() clearly enumerates keys. If really want to debate that, go to chat. 2. The motivation behind not including a method on an object for a very common purpose - from the original question: 'my intention is to understand the design of Javascript, and what purpose the somewhat unintuitive mechanism of fetching keys serves.' Spamming the site with continual restatements of 'they couldn't add it later' does not answer the question of why they didn't include it earlier.

Comment: @nailer: You really need to read more closely. I said it's not *"a mechanism of enumeration"*. JavaScript already has a mechanism of enumerating keys. It's called `for-in`. That syntax *enumerates the (enumerable) keys of an Object*. I've answered your question. The unintuitive mechanism of *collecting* keys *(which is what `Object.keys` does)* stems from the fact that shadowed properties cause issues, so they don't want to do that. It's very simple.

Comment: Why they didn't include it earlier? They obviously either didn't think a method for collecting keys was necessary, or it simply didn't occur to them. There are many things not in the language. It was a late addition. As such, they added it as a property to `Object`. Who knows. At this point, you seem to be trolling.

Comment: Imagine some existing code that does `if (my_obj.keys) { /* do something */ }` Add a `keys` property to `Object.prototype`, and now that code is broken.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15237/discussion-between-nailer-and-am-not-i-am)

Comment: @amnotiam 1. you're now defining a difference between something that enumerates keys and a mechanism of enumeration - I think this is splitting hairs, but you can continue that discussion in chat. 2. Thanks for amending your answer - I think it should be fairly obvious that languages are created and initially designed before they are used, and that my question clearly pertains to JS design. I've edited your answer to focus on the new material - which does actually answer the design question - and removed the answer around retrofitting, which was not mentioned in the question.

Comment: @nailer: There is a distinction. Whether or not the underlying implementation enumerates the keys in order to provide the result of `Object.keys` is an implementation detail that ultimately has no bearing on the JavaScript code that is written. *(Yes, it likely does enumerate under the hood.)* Maybe you were talking about a method of enumeration that fits a functional paradigm. If so, that's an interesting question, but ultimately `Object.keys` doesn't fulfill that feature, at least not without `forEach`. `Object.keys(obj).forEach(fn)`, as I'd assume you're accustomed to using.

Comment: ...FYI, even if they had originally created a functional means of object enumeration at version 1, there's no guarantee that it would be on `Object.prototype` for reason I gave in my original answer. The more properties on `Object.prototype`, the more there is to work around when using an Object. The retrofitting aspect only *adds* to that issue.

Answer (score 4):

Feel free to make your own, but the more properties you add to the `Object` prototype, the higher chance you'll collide. These collisions will most likely break any third party javascript library, and any code that relies on a `for...in` loop.

```
Object.prototype.keys = function () {
    return Object.keys(this);
};

for (var key in {}) {
    // now i'm getting 'keys' in here, wtf?
}

var something = {
    keys: 'foo'
};

something.keys(); // error
```

Comment: This code breaks jQuery and many others, and you didn't mention it.

Comment: @Esailija i thought the collision warning covered that, clarified.

Comment: You *can* add properties there without breaking anything, by using non-enumerable properties. That's how the existing stuff on Object.prototype works, after all.

Comment: @Esailija the only way to emulate a non-enumerable property is by modifying each and every `for...in` loop, right?

Comment: It cannot be emulated, you simply specify it when creating the property: `Object.defineProperty( Object.prototype, "keys", {value: function(){}, enumerable: false})` But this is a different issue from collission, which cannot be solved.

Comment: @nailer: The language *could* have included it on `Object.prototype`, and made it non enumerable, just like it does with the other properties. That was not a barrier at all *(assuming language design is the consideration)*.

Comment: @nailer - the for..in loop iterates over non-own keys so that you can get properties from the prototype chain. You can then test individual properties to see if they belong to the object directly using `.hasOwnProperty()`.

Comment: A lot of misunderstanding here. Collision refers to a simple shadowing inconvenience, which is the reason stuff is put on the constructor. The enumerability is a completely different problem and can easily be solved, as is done for the other methods in Object.prototype. This answer is false (As in it's not the collision that make other libraries not work but the enumerability) and missing the point.

Comment: @Esailija Thanks for the insight. Thinking about it I agree with your reasoning - it's the ennumerability that's the issue. I've posted a modified version of your comment above as an answer - I hope you don't mind.

Comment: @nailer yeah but it's still missing the point. The `.keys` *could* be on `Object.prototype` as non-enumerable property and all enumeration and jQuery would work just fine. Yet it was chosen to be placed in the `Object` constructor. And am not i am gave a reasonable reason for that.

Comment: @Esailija there is a difference between shadowing and collision, right? in this case, don't we have a collision and not shadowing since we are *overwriting* the `keys` property?

Comment: @jbabey A custom `keys` property on an object would shadow the one in prototype, thus you would need to access `Object.prototype.keys` explicitly. `var a = {keys: 0}; a.keys(); //oops`

Comment: @Esailija i understand now, it is shadowing because you are still able to access the original one through `Object.prototype.keys` - it is not actually overwritten. thank you.