# Why are so many Object utilities defined on the constructor and not the prototype

Tags: javascript, api, ecmascript-5

In ES5 lots of Object utilities are defined on the constructor, not the prototype (e.g. `defineProperty` and `keys`). What are the reasons behind this design choice? To me, `myObject.keys()` seems like a much better API than `Object.keys(myObject)`

Comment: To know the actual reasons, you would have had to have been involved in the discussion about this new feature when it was being designed.  I doubt you're going to find that actual information here.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922619/javascript-why-object-keyssomeobject-rather-than-someobject-keys and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19941499/why-is-object-keys-not-object-prototype-keys