# For standard built-in objects in JavaScript, what are the reasons for defining a method in the object's prototype vs. the object's constructor?

Tags: javascript, constructor, prototype

JavaScript noob here. I understand that in general, in choosing to define a method in the constructor vs the prototype, the constructor approach allows for the use of closures by taking advantage of local variables defined in the constructor, as described here:

[Declaring javascript object method in constructor function vs. in prototype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9772307/declaring-javascript-object-method-in-constructor-function-vs-in-prototype)

Does a similar reasoning apply for **standard built-in objects**? For ex. I'm looking through [MDN documentation for the Object constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) and I see methods defined within both the constructor and the prototype. What were reasons for designing these standard object's methods to be defined in either the constructor or the prototype?

Comment: Welcome to [so]! It seems your question is the same as [Javascript: why Object.keys(someobject), rather than someobject.keys?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922619/javascript-why-object-keyssomeobject-rather-than-someobject-keys) Please let me know if this is not the case.

Comment: Thanks! The answers to that post bring up a good point about the consequences of adding shadowing properties to `Object.prototype`, which adds one reason to the solution to my post, but the rest of the answers seem more specific to `Object.keys`. I'm curious to know of any more reasons if they do exist.

Comment: Another question that's very similar is [Why were ES5 Object methods not added to Object.prototype?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9735026/why-were-es5-object-methods-not-added-to-object-prototype)

Comment: methods defined "on" a constructor are static methods that can be easily applied to non-instances.